# Ecto and jsonb_to_recordset

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, jsonb

I have the following query that I am currently running as raw sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM phrases, jsonb_to_recordset(phrases.translations)
AS x(text text)
WHERE x.text
LIKE '%hello%'
```

Where `hello` is a query string passed in by the UI. How could I rewrite this to use the ecto query syntax? I'm confused how to leverage fragments in combination with `jsonb_to_recordset`.

Comment: What have you tried? What failed in your attempt?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin to be honest I wouldn't even know where to start. Right now it works as a SQL statement, so I'm just using that, but it would be nice to know how to use this with Ecto